# Не работает изменение кнопок для разных экранов (@media screen)

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Пытался реализовать изменение кнопок для разных экранов, а в итоге выполняется только первый

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.btn {width: calc(1200px/3)}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
.btn {width: 100%}
}
```

Comment: выполняется когда? На 1200+?

Comment: Да, а вот второй напрочь игнорирует

Comment: ну, эм, логично .... второе условие выполнится при макс ширине 1199 .... (min-width - от и до плюс бесконечности, max-width - от и до минус бесконечности)

Comment: Проблема то в том, что не выполняется при уменьшении экрана

Comment: Компьютера под рукой пока нет, но по идее должно работать, посмотрите не пропустили ли вы `;` после каждой инструкции.

Comment: А вы добавили meta viewport?

Comment: Проверь, есть в `<head>` это `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Если нет, добавте.

Comment: Был @viewport в стиле, добавил в meta - ничего не изменилось

Comment: Так ты глянь в девтулз отображаются у тебя вообще медиа, или просто перекрываются другими стилями .. ?

Comment: Первый медиа да, а второй все никак

Comment: Все, полноценная ошибка найдена - container из bootstrap задавал свой стиль, и почему-то не перекрывался вторым